# NULL Date Calculation SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have 6 Columns at SQL Server table SLA
I tried to add compained column QASLA from the below
Created - Closed Columns  are datetime - Not NULL

EsculationDate - [EsculationFeedback] 
[InternalEsculationReplay] - [InternalEsculationDate] Columns are 
datetime type and Could be NULL values

```
  alter table SLA
  add QASLA as

  iif((Closed=null),datediff(dd,getdate(),Created),
  (datediff(dd,Closed,Created))-datediff(dd,IIF(COALESCE ([EsculationDate],0)>COALESCE ([InternalEsculationDate],0),COALESCE ([InternalEsculationDate],0),COALESCE ([EsculationDate],0)),
  IIF(COALESCE ([EsculationFeedback],0)>COALESCE ([InternalEsculationReplay],0),COALESCE ([EsculationFeedback],0),COALESCE ([InternalEsculationReplay],0))))
```

When i try to insert a new record

```
insert into [dbo].[SLA]
([Created],[EsculationDate],[EsculationFeedback],[Closed])
values('10-Jun-15','10-Jun-15','15-Jun-15','15-Jun-15')
```

QASLA Result = -42173
I need to get value 0 as created date = 10 Jun and Closed Date = 15 Jun mins (EsculationDate+EsculationFeedback) 
I try to use ISNULL also

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure I understand your question but you `IIF` is useless here because it will never be equal to NULL. You cannot compare a value to NULL and must use `IS NULL`:

```
alter table SLA
  add QASLA as

  iif((Closed is null),datediff(dd,getdate(),Created),
  (datediff(dd,Closed,Created))-datediff(dd,IIF(COALESCE ([EsculationDate],0)>COALESCE ([InternalEsculationDate],0),COALESCE ([InternalEsculationDate],0),COALESCE ([EsculationDate],0)),
  IIF(COALESCE ([EsculationFeedback],0)>COALESCE ([InternalEsculationReplay],0),COALESCE ([EsculationFeedback],0),COALESCE ([InternalEsculationReplay],0))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of your DATEDIFF statements appear to have the dates the "wrong way around".  You should have the earlier date as the second argument and the later date as the third argument to return the positive days between them.

Also, you are treating NULL dates as 0 in many cases, where 0 will be interpreted as a "very early date".

I would have expected your handling of NULLs to work very differently here? You can't use equality comparison between a column and NULL, you need to use the IS NULL statement instead, e.g. "Closed = NULL" becomes "Closed IS NULL".

Finally, you say Closed Date is NOT NULL, but the very first thing you do in your script is to compare it to NULL.